# MenuetOS alternative

Tags: distributions

I have been looking at MenuetOS, a simple graphical OS written entirely in FASM. Are there any other lightweight operating system which written entirely in one programming language such as C programming language or another?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't entirely an answer but have you checked out https://www.kolibrios.org/en/ ??

It is forked from MenuetOS and been further streamlined and cleaned up a lot. Also has far more addon/plugin support.

It's possible it can be ported into C although C++ will be required for most of the base system operations.

There are tons of other operating systems built from the Unix/Linux philosophy using C and C++ that are quite small. Like DSL(Damn Small Linux) and TCL(Tiny Core Linux) that are under 50MB's with a GUI and functional set of software.

Just examples. I know this didn't quite answer your question but hopefully it gets you thinking in the right direction.